# build a tree using two columns and count the level

Tags: python, dataframe, recursion, tree, networkx

I have a somewhat similar question to this one and therefore, I used the same example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722740/hierarchical-data-efficiently-build-a-list-of-every-descendant-for-each-node#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722740/hierarchical-data-efficiently-build-a-list-of-every-descendant-for-each-node#_=_)

I have a two column data set depicting multiple child-parent relationships for companies that form a large tree. I would like to use this to count the height of the tree.

#### Original Input:

```
   child  parent
8   1000    1000
1   2010    1000
7   2100    1000
5   2110    1000
3   3000    2110
2   3011    2010
4   3033    2100
0   3102    2010
6   3111    2110
```

What I would like to do is to get the height of this tree. In this specific case, the height would be three.

I am not sure how to do this in Python or PySpark. I don't know whether this is possible. My thinking pattern was to first build a tree using some package f.e. and then count the height. However, I have no clue on how to do this in Python/PySpark at all. I am a starter in creating trees in programming languages and don't know a lot about building my own tree with the use of programming though I can draw it by hand.

Comment: You can either build the tree yourself with a dictionary and/or list or you can use a library such as `networkx`. If you are going to build it yourself, I suggest stepping away from the computer and working through your example by hand. How would you go about building a tree on a piece of paper from your example child/parent data?

Comment: I cant import the image. But if  you click on the link in my question, the original post already added an image. I do understand how the tree is build but I don't know how to create one using Python. I guess I was unclear about that in my main post and I have edited my main post.

Comment: I sm using my phone to type this comment. I will eventually answer your question tomorrow. 
The idea is to declare a Node class, which may have a list of children or even not. If it has no list of children it is a leaf. This is the case of  &#39;3000&#39;, &#39;3011&#39;, &#39;3033&#39;,  &#39;3102&#39; and &#39;3111&#39; in your example.
To get the height of a node, you consider the max(height) of all its children +1.
If it&#39;s a leaf its height is of course 1.

Comment: @Meziane 

I would appreciate it if you could give me a code on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must try to solve your problem before asking for help and provide the code you have used. Anyway here is what you need:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, name, desc):
    self.name = name
    self.desc = desc


  def height(self):
    if len(self.desc)==0:
      return 1
    else:
      return 1 + max(len(child.desc) for child in n1000.desc)


n3000 =Node("3000", []);
n3011 =Node("3011", []);
n3033 =Node("3033", []);
n3102 =Node("3102", []);
n3111 =Node("3111", []);




n2010 = Node("2010", [n3011, n3102]);
n2100 = Node("2100",[n3033]);
n2110 = Node("2110", [n3000, n3111]);

n1000 = Node("1000", [n2010, n2100, n2110]);

#print(max(len(child.desc) for child in n1000.desc))

print(n1000.name, n2010.height())
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used the treelib library to build my tree. I guess I'll update my question to include my own solution. I think your solution is perhaps better (I used a package and you actually defined a function yourself).

Comment: @[Eren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5691725/eren): It's never late for a sweet word: You are welcome