# using recursive function in python to find end-to-end lineage in a data frame

Tags: python, recursion

all. I have this data frame with two columns: **source** and **target.**

| source | target |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | c |
| z | v |
| e | a |
| f | a |
| g | b |
| h | g |
| i | g |
| j | i |
| x | k |
| y | z |

for target "c", it has two sources: "a" and "b", then for "a", it has two sources: "e" and "f", etc.

I would like to use a recursive function to find all lineages starting from "c". The expected outcome should be:

| source | target |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | c |
| e | a |
| f | a |
| g | b |
| h | g |
| i | g |
| j | i |

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried to use for loop in side a recursive function, however it didn't do the job i expected.

Comment: How is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: Please, paste your current code

Comment: Your data describes a tree and what you want to do is a tree traversal. I suggest starting by building a dictionary that maps every source to the list of its targets (or every target to the list of every source, depending on what you mean by "lineage starting from c").

Comment: Some pretty great answers here where they start with a dataframe similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722740/hierarchical-data-efficiently-build-a-list-of-every-descendant-for-each-node

Comment: just added the expected outcome. thanks guys!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.